# Best way to return top 10, but first row need to be a sum total of all rows

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table with 2 bill. rows. I am not able to show them all in a browser with out crash and will thereby only return top 10 rows but the first row of my table need to be a sum of all 2 bill. rows.

I was idea is to select all rows and calculate the total, and afterword union on same table with only the top 10 rows. This way I don't need to run the same query twice.

But what is your experiences and ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Can you  show your table and what you expect to get. so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select SUM(total) from bill
union
select top (10) * from bill
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer2005+

In my example I numbered rows function ROW_NUMBER() and if rows = 11 then replace total on SUM(total) with OVER() clause

```
SELECT TOP(11) CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) = 11 THEN SUM(total) OVER() ELSE total END
FROM dbo.your_table
```